# Hide ManyToOne field in REST API in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot with simple REST API on server. I have 2 resources: users and articles. Here is Article class:

```
@Entity(name = "article")
public class Article {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String text;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

    public User getUser() { // I need this method.
        return user;
    }

    // All other setters and getters.

}
```

Now, if I fetch some article by its ID using REST API, response looks like:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "text": "Content of article...",
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "user@email.com",
        "password": "$2a$10$CbsH93d8s5NX6Gx/N5zcwemUJ7YXXjRIQAE2InW9zyHlcTh6zWrua"
    }
}
```

How can I exclude `user` field from response? If I remove `Article.getUser` method, everything works fine and response looks like:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "text": "Content of article..."
}
```

This is desired result. However, I need `Article.getUser`, because e. g. if someone want delete article, I need check, if author of the request is author of the article, so user cannot delete articles of other users.

Comment: Use @JsonIgnore on user field

Comment: Suggestion keep data layers separate from presentation layers, start using DTOs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @JsonIgnore on like below:

```
@JsonIgnore 
private User user;
```

The other way is `Projection` in which you have more control on what should be included in response.